# Generic Class Doesn't print 2nd Parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I created a generic class here's my code

```
using System;

public class Node<T>
{
    T data;
    Node<T> link;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> link)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data : " + this.data , this.link);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Node<string> node1 = new Node<string>("Some", null);
        Node<string> node2 = new Node<string>("Thing", node1);

        node1.Write();
        node2.Write();
        //to write on the console
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I'm just confused or my syntax is really wrong . Please tell me

So i wrote

```
node1.Write()
node2.Write()
```

Should The output be

Node1

> Some

Node2

> Thing Some

I am right or not?? Please enlighten me .

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Data : " + this.data , this.link);`. Where is `this.link` supposed to be printed there? Please read on `string.Format`

Comment: also have a look at `ToString`-method and how to override it in order to print a complex object (e.g. your `Node`-class) .

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Data : " + this.data, this.link.data);` ?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Oh so i can't print like this `Some Thing Some`?

Comment: @Lucifer changed it to this `Console.WriteLine("Data : " + this.data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to HimBromBeere's answer that doesn't use recursion or overriding the `ToString` method is to change your `Write` function to this:

```
public void Write()
{
    Console.Write("Data: ");
    Console.Write($"{data}");

    var next = link;
    while(next != null)
    {
        Console.Write($", {link.data}");
        next = next.link;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this sir `$`

Comment: It's [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), basically a nicer way of doing `string.Format`

Comment: Ow Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As your `link`-property is of type `Node` and `Console.WriteLine` will use the types `ToString`-method in order to print an instance of your class to console, you should overwite `object.ToString`:

```
class Node<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ this.data }, { this.link?.ToString() }";
    }
}
```

If you don´t do this `Console.WriteLine` will simply fall back to `object.ToString`, which will only return something like `MyNamespace.Node'1'`.

Than within your `Write`-method you could also call this one:

```
public void Write()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Data: " + ToString());
}
```

Comment: This will not compile sir

Comment: This line is all I need `this.link?.ToString()` thank you

Comment: Minor warning though, this is using recursion so if you have a lot of nodes, you might get a stack overflow exception

Comment: Could you explain sir thanks `this.link?.ToString()` doing

Comment: @BoonMingProg It checks if `link` is `null` and if so simoply returns `null`, otherwise it calls `link.ToString` and returns that instead. Just a shorthand for `return link == null ? null : link.ToString()`.

Comment: Oh, and this leaves a trailing comma in the output. :)